# Sharepoint wss 3.0 authentication

Tags: sharepoint, authentication

I have developed one site in sharepoint wss3.0 when i type in the url i.e. http://testserver/default.aspx i am first asked username and password On successful login(I have created user from sharepoint central admin site) i am redirected to my site's login page.

then i have do login to access my site.

Now what i want to do is combine both logins i.e. when i login to my server using sharepoint user's username and password i want to be redirected to my site's home page. I should not be redirected to my site's login page

What should i do? Do i need to code in sharepoint's default login page present in _layouts directory? If yes how can i access login.aspx.cs ??

Plz help

Comment: Can't you make both sites to use your Active Directory credential? This way you will get all benefits from Single Sign On (SSO)

Comment: Yes i can do it but i dont know how to redirect to my home page instead of my site's login page..where do i need to write code for it??

Comment: Also I need to set some session variables from my site's login page as the user is redirected to the home page according to the designation like developer,senior developer,project manager..so if i wish to remove my site's login page i need to do all the coding in sharepoint's default login page

Comment: How have you configured your Web Application?  What Authentication Provider have you configured for your Web Application?  How have you configured security in your Site Collection?  Sorry to be so blunt, but your question makes no sense to me so I wonder if you have misconfigured the Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

Your application (assuming it's an ASP.NET application) needs to be deployed into sharepoint's _layouts directory, typically in a custom subfolder, in order to leverage session state and shared authentication.

12/TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS/yourapp/default.aspx

-Oisin